# Unambiguous expression of binary string

Tags: combinatorics

What would an unambiguous expression of a binary string be if every block of one is a multiple of 45 and every block of 0 is multiple of 20?
I'm kind of new to combinatorics.
How would I go about to find this expression?

Comment: Try starting from the following unambigous expression $\{1\}^∗\{\{0\}\{0\}^∗\{1\}\{1\}^∗\}^∗\{0\}^∗$ for the set of binary strings, where $\{A\}^*=\emptyset \cup \{A\} \cup \{A,A\}\cup \cdots$.

Comment: @Condo sorry i'm still kind of new to combinatorics so i'm not sure how i can use that expression to go further

Answer (score 1):

Simply replace $0$ with $0^{20}$ (where $0^{20}:=\{00\cdots0\}$ i.e. 20 $0$'s) and $1$ with $1^{45}:=\{1111\cdots 111\}$ 45 $1$'s) in the unambiguous expression $\{1\}^∗\{\{0\}\{0\}^∗\{1\}\{1\}^∗\}^∗\{0\}^∗$ for the set of all binary strings and convince yourself that $$\{1^{45}\}^∗\{\{0^{20}\}\{0^{20}\}^∗\{1^{45}\}\{1^{45}\}^∗\}^∗\{0^{20}\}^∗$$ is an unambigious expression for your desired set of strings.